# Can I change the parent of a subsite in SharePoint Foundations 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sub-site

Is there any way to move a subsite from one parent to another in SharePoint Foundations 2010?

I know it is done in the "content and structure" features but SharePoint Foundations does not have the "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature or the "Office SharePoint Server Publishing" feature which enable the "content and structure" feature.

Has anyone been able to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the powershell command.

first [export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the subsite

```
[Export-SPWeb][2] -Identity -Path [-ItemUrl ] [-IncludeUserSecurity] [-IncludeVersions] [-NoFileCompression] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

Now you need to import it at desitnation:

```
[Import-SPWeb][3] [-Identity] <SPWebPipeBind> -Path <String> [-ActivateSolutions <SwitchParameter>] [-AssignmentCollection <SPAssignmentCollection>] [-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]] [-Force ] [-IncludeUserSecurity ]  [-UpdateVersions <Append | Overwrite | Ignore>]
```

Another method you can try to [save the subsite](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2420856) as `Save As Template`.

Comment: I just tried the save as template method and that seemed to work. Haven't had any experience with the powershell so I'm a little cautious to try it.

Comment: we want to make sure to solve the issue in either way....so enjoy the sharepointing

Comment: That's fine, what abt the save as template method?

Comment: That one worked.